# I'm getting an error in React while connecting it to the firebase "Could not find module in path: 'firebase' relative to '/src/firebase-config.js'"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

This is the error I'm getting:-
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vF1g0.png)
This is my first time using Firebase, So I don't know about it much. But after seeing somany tutorials it seems like this is the right way, but nothing is working. I'm using latest firebase version. Installed & Uninstalled firebase couple of times, but nothing happened.

```
//App.js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Todo from "./Todo";
import { Button, FormControl, Input, InputLabel } from "@material-ui/core";
import "./App.css";
import db from "./firebase-config";


function App() {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([
    
  ]);
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    // this code fires when the app loads
    db.collection("todos").onSnapshot(snapshot => {
      console.log(snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data()));
      // setTodos(snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data().todo))
    })
  }, [])

  const addTodo = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setTodos([...todos, input]);
    setInput("");
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>React Todo with Firebase</h1>
      <form>
        <FormControl>
          <InputLabel>✅Write a Todo...</InputLabel>
          <Input onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)} value={input} />
        </FormControl>
        <Button
          disabled={!input}
          type="submit"
          onClick={addTodo}
          variant="contained"
          color="primary"
        >
          Add Todo
        </Button>
      </form>

      <ul>
        {todos.map((todo) => (
         <Todo text={todo} />
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

//firebase-config.js

import firebase from 'firebase';

const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: "AIzaSsdfsdfBbWj6IbdKr0la5cx4k75fcS_qvMU",
    authDomain: "todo-app-8sdf10.firebaseapp.com",
    projectId: "todo-app-sdf110",
    storageBucket: "todo-app-8sdf10.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "26sdfreact6661358",
    appId: "1:260256sdf358:web:99eafsdfbd6099cb748b7f",
    measurementId: "G-EH6HsdfHRD5R"
});

const db = firebaseApp.firestore();
export default db;
```

Comment: please dont post your api keys on stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your import to:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
```

This way you can keep using existing code/syntax. Though I'll recommend checking out the [new Modular SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade#get_the_version_9_sdk) which has a different syntax but has performance benefits.

Comment: Thanks for the help, the below code worked!

`import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';`
`import 'firebase/compat/firestore';`

Comment: Hey @PavanSargar, if my answer was useful you can accept it by clicking the ✔ icon.

Answer (score 0):

From the firebase documentation : https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#web-version-9

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
```

You can then initialize your app doing the following :

```
const firebaseApp = initializeApp({
  apiKey: '### FIREBASE API KEY ###',
  authDomain: '### FIREBASE AUTH DOMAIN ###',
  projectId: '### CLOUD FIRESTORE PROJECT ID ###'
});

const db = getFirestore();
```

Also note that you should not share your project config variables like this.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this solution. BTW I've slightly changed config variables before sharing.

Comment: Thanks for the help, the above code still gave me an error, but this one worked

`import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';`
`import 'firebase/compat/firestore';`